# Count repeated occurrences in a CSV?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a CSV with columns that look like the following:

```
Team    Other Data  More Data   Result  Time
Knicks      A          F         Loss    2p
Celtics     B          E         Win     2p
Lakers      C          D         Loss    3p
Lakers      D          C         Loss    4p
Knicks      E          B         Win     4p
Lakers      F          A         Win     5p
```

How can I read the CSV and output the wins and losses of each team?

For example, my desired output would be the following:

> ```
> 1 Loss Knicks
> 1 Win Knicks
> 1 Win Celtics
> 2 Loss Lakers
> 1 Win Lakers
> ```

Right now, I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r team result
do
  echo $team, $result
done < teams.csv
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Team, Result   
Knicks, Loss
Celtics, Win
Lakers, Loss
Lakers, Loss
Knicks, Win
```

How can I count and store the number of occurrences of each result for every team? Ideally I'd like this data sorted by team.

Comment: Please show us the original input rather than human readable ASCII art.

Comment: The first example ... "that it looks like" is not useful to generate good answers. Your script indicates that it's comma-separated. Show the actual (representative) input.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are myriad examples of working with CSV on this Stack alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using arrays in `awk`

If the fields of the input file are separated by one or more whitespace characters, then you don't have to declare the field separator:

```
awk 'NR>1 && NF { league[$1][$4]++ } END { for ( team in league ) for ( results in league[team] ) print league[team][results],results,team }' teams.txt
```

The same code, formatted for the screen:

```
awk 'NR>1 && NF { league[$1][$4]++ }
     END { for ( team in league )
           for ( results in league[team] )
           print league[team][results],results,team }' teams.txt
```

Here, `league[$1][$4]++` counts the numbers (`$4`, the fourth field) of wins and losses for each team (`$1`, the first field) in the league (the input file).

`NR>1` means that `awk` will ignore the header (the first line).

Similarly, `NF` (shorthand for `NF>0`) means that `awk` will only examine lines containing at least one field.  In other words, `NF` skips blank lines.

The `NR>1 && NF` section examines the input file and creates the array.  When that is finished, the `END` section prints the array.

If the fields of the input file are comma-separated, then add `BEGIN { FS="," ; OFS=" " }` to set the input (`FS`) and output (`OFS`) field separators:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," ; OFS=" " } NR>1 && NF { league[$1][$4]++ } END { for ( team in league ) for ( results in league[team] ) print league[team][results],results,team }' teams.csv
```

The same code, formatted for the screen:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," ; OFS=" " }
         NR>1 && NF { league[$1][$4]++ }
         END { for ( team in league )
               for ( results in league[team] )
               print league[team][results],results,team }' teams.csv
```

Output:

```
1 Win Knicks
1 Loss Knicks
1 Win Lakers
2 Loss Lakers
1 Win Celtics
```

Add `| sort -t " " -k 3 -k 2,2` to the end of that code, to sort by team and then by results per team.

Sorted output:

```
1 Win Celtics
1 Loss Knicks
1 Win Knicks
2 Loss Lakers
1 Win Lakers
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is sort the file and pass it to `uniq -c` to count unique occurrences:

```
sort teams.csv | uniq -c
```

That should produce output like this:

```
      1 Celtics,Win
      1 Knicks,Loss
      1 Knicks,Win
      2 Lakers,Loss
```

Comment: That is nice for getting the output, but in my original question, I said that I wanted to count and store the number of occurrences. If my input file happened to contain other information and I only wanted to read/extract information from the Team and Result column, that solution would not be viable.

Comment: @vipertherapper then you should show a representative input sample so that you can get good answers.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I edited the original question.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU datamash (and awk to rearrange the columns, if that matters to you):

```
$ datamash -W --header-in groupby 1,4 count 4 < teams.csv | awk '{print $3, $2, $1}'
1 Loss Knicks
1 Win Celtics
2 Loss Lakers
1 Win Knicks
1 Win Lakers
```

Note that because we **don't** ask datamash to sort, this only groups results that are already adjacent.

*If your data are really **comma** separated then replace* `-W` *by* `-t,`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `sort` and then pipe it into `uniq -c` but that will include `Team, Result`.

To avoid that:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 {print $4,$1}' team.csv | sort -k2 | uniq -c
```

To explain each section:

- `awk 'NR>1 {print $4,$1}'` - Prints all the lines greater than the first with the result followed by the team as specified with columns 4 and 1 for the team and the result.
- `sort -k2` - Sorts by the team as it becomes the second column after `awk` operates.
- `uniq -c` - Counts the number of unique occurrences

The output sorted by team:

```
1 Win Celtics
1 Loss Knicks
1 Win Knicks
2 Loss Lakers
1 Win Lakers
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this output:  `1  Celtics,B,E,Win,2p`, continuing on for the rest of the rows.

Comment: @vipertherapper I copied your csv file in exactly the way that you have it and used the command in my answer. If it looks like what you've provided and you're using what I have then you should get the same result.

Comment: @vipertherapper Are you using the exact command in my answer? The `awk` part will only print columsn 4 and 1 which are the team and the result. It won't print anything from the other columns.

Comment: I am using the exact command, yes. I'm trying to figure out why we're getting different outputs. I even tried recreating my CSV to no avail.

Comment: @vipertherapper Copy the csv that you have in your question into a new file and then run my command on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80209/discussion-between-vipertherapper-and-nasir-riley).